# Is there a way to share global constant in Swift/Obj-C and Metal code

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, metal

I know it's possible to declare custom structs in Obj-C header file, and reuse this one declaration in both Metal shaders as well as in Obj-C/Swift host code. Can we declare and define global constants in one place without duplication in such a way that they will be accessible in both Metal and host code in Swift/Obj-C as well?

The only way I have come up by myself is to use `#define SOME_CONST 123.45f` in this same shared Obj-C header file, but `#define` is not constant per se and I'm looking to more standard typed definition.

Comment: I think defines are okay, but you can use macros as well to be more expressive. In case of program scope constants in Metal, you want your constants to be `constant constexpr` and in Objective-C, if you are using the C++ dialect of it, you can just keep it as constexpr. You can use `#ifdef  __METAL_VERSION_` to define a different version of `CONSTANT` macro or whatever you wanna call it that will generate the left hand of the constant definition and use it as `CONSTANT(int) myConstant = 123;`.

Comment: If you are using pure Objective-C, it might be more challenging, since you would either just keep using defines or create a separate `extern` declaration and a definition in `.m` file.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy thank you! I haven't thought of conditional macro myself. I use `#define CONSTANT constant constexpr` for Metal and `#define CONSTANT const static` for Swift. Worked out okay so far.